# UIWebView isn't accepting multiple touches

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

To display attachments on a messaging system I'm developing for my app, I've got a `UIWebView` which is presented in a `ModalViewController`, displaying the file contained in the attachment.

If it's any help, the code I'm using to display the file is as follows:

```
NSUrl docUrl = NSUrl.FromFilename(filePath);
NSUrlRequest request = new NSUrlRequest(docUrl);
webView.LoadRequest(request);
```

(filePath is a string of the Path to the file).

This works fantastic for displaying PDFs, text documents etc.

However, the `UIWebView` isn't accepting any multi touch gestures (pinch to zoom etc) - I've set

```
webView.MultipleTouchEnabled = true;
webView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
```

yet still no luck. Will I have to use a `GestureRecognizer` or am I missing something obvious?

I'm aware I'm using Monotouch but Objective C answers are more than welcome : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that `scalesPageToFit` is set to `NO`?  That might cause similar behavior to what you are seeing.

Comment: This worked thank you very much. If you read my earlier comment, ignore that, I editted the wrong file, which would explain why it didn't effect this web view; hadn't had my morning coffee by then !